# How to do a linq group by

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq query in my aspnet core application that is returning more rows then it should. The query is as follows.

```
public List<csAutoComplete> GetAutoComplete(string Type, string filter)
{
string[] GasCodesnotListed = { "F97", "F98", "F99" };
Model1 = from x in _context.TblGascodes
    where ((x.GasCode.StartsWith("F13") || x.GasName.StartsWith("F13")) &&
            !GasCodesnotListed.Contains(x.FedclusterCode))
    orderby x.GasCode
    group x by new csAutoComplete { ACCode = x.GasCode, ACName = x.GasName } into Alpha
    select new csAutoComplete  <=== (Is this the issue???)
        {
        ACCode = Alpha.Key.ACCode,
        ACName = Alpha.Key.ACCode + " - " + Alpha.Key.ACName
        };
return Model1.ToList();
}
```

}
returns (7) results

So I pasted into LINQ pad and got the result I expected of (1)

```
string[] GasCodesnotListed = { "F97", "F98", "F99" };
TblGasCodes
   .Where (
      x => 
        ((x.GasCode.StartsWith ("F13") || x.GasName.StartsWith ("F13")) && 
           !(GasCodesnotListed.Contains (x.GasCode))
        )
   )
   .OrderBy (x => x.GasCode)
   .GroupBy (
      x => 
         new  
         {
            ACCode = x.GasCode, 
            ACName = x.GasName
         }
   )
   .Select (
      Alpha => 
         new  
         {
            ACCode = Alpha.Key.ACCode, 
            ACName = ((Alpha.Key.ACCode + " - ") + Alpha.Key.ACName)
         }
   )
```

The only difference seems to be in the new csAutoComplete. If that is a class definition why should that make a difference? How do I resolve this.

Comment: If `csAutoComplete` doesn't have `Equals` overridden, it'll be comparing by `Object.ReferenceEquals()`, while for purposes of GroupBy, anonymous types (as in your second example) are identical if all properties are identical. I would use the anonymous type for group-bying.

Comment: When you say anonymous type, I don't understand that. Do you mean create new variables and removing the class?

Comment: In your second version, you have `new  
         {
            ACCode = x.GasCode, 
            ACName = x.GasName
         }` -- you're creating an instance of an anonymous type there.

Comment: its because there will be multiple references of `csAutoComplete` and there are not the same even in the values are same unless you have overridden the `Equals` and `GetHashcode` methods.. anonymous types don't have this problem.

Comment: @TomS See update to my answer.

Comment: you need to `Group By` into anonymous types and then select into your known type `CsAutoComplete`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you overrode `Equals` in `csAutoComplete`, `GroupBy` will compare instances of `csAutoComplete` using `Object.ReferenceEquals()` or some equivalent. Two instances with identical `GasCode` and `GasName` properties will be two separate group keys. If you've got seven items coming in, that'll group them in seven groups of one item each.

This is not the case with anonymous types. Separate instances with the same values for their properties will be treated as equal by `GroupBy`.

```
var items = new[] { 0, 0 }.Select(n => new { x = n, y = n.ToString() }).ToArray();

var groups = items.GroupBy(x => x).ToArray();

//  Not equal here!
var aretheyequal = items[0] == items[1];

//  But GroupBy isn't fooled: There's only one group
var groupcount = groups.Length;
```

Use your anonymous type for a group key -- or overload `Equals` on `csAutoComplete` if you like to live on the edge. It can cause funny bugs, in my experience (or more accurately, programmers write funny bugs by failing to be mindful of the changes it introduces). I prefer not to go there.

Hence, I think your `GetAutoComplete` method is OK, except for the group by line, which I would change to this:

```
group x by new { ACCode = x.GasCode, ACName = x.GasName } into Alpha
```

The later reference to `ACCode = Alpha.Key.ACCode` etc. shouldn't need to change, since the property names are the same.

Comment: This would be correct when it's LINQ to objects. However, I think that `_context.TblGascodes` is not an `IEnumerable` but an `IQueryable` from Entity Framework or LINQ to SQL. So the expression `Model1` as a whole will be translated into SQL and the grouping with or without `csAutoComplete` shouldn't make a difference. @Tom, could you shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, there seems to be an important difference in GasCodesnotListed.Contains (one looks at FedclusterCode, the other at GasCode):

```
where (x.GasCode.StartsWith ("F13") && !GasCodesnotListed.Contains (x.**FedclusterCode**))
```

...versus...

```
.Where (
  x => 
    (
       x.GasCode.StartsWith ("F13") && 
       !(GasCodesnotListed.Contains (x.**GasCode**))
    )
)
```